# JQuery - converting string to an object and adding "click" event not working in a module pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, each

I would like to create module pattern for my JS, and I would like to store all DOM references in object, but it has to be string since, DOM is creating later. Later I would like to use function to add "click" events to all stored selectors, problem is that no matter what I would try I can't convert them to proper jQuery objects somehow. Classic $(...) seems not to work, and I don't know what's going on. I get "TypeError: a is not an object" now, with previous tries i had "b is undefined" and so on.

How to fix that ??

```js
 var Obj = {
 
        dom: {
            element1: ".image",
            element2:".image2"
        },
        init: function () {
                $.each(Obj.dom, Obj.setup);
        },
        setup: function () {
            
            console.log(this); // String ".image" -GOOD
            var item = $(this);
            console.log(item); // Object ".", "i", "m" ... - kinda weird, 
            // why is this divided by 1 character ??
            
            $(item).on("click", function () { // TypeError: a is not an object
              console.log('works');
            });
            
        }
 };
 
 Obj.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this` is not exactly string. It is a object and you need to convert it to string.

```
console.log(typeof this) // object
console.log(this + '');  // String ".image"
var item = $(this + ''); // works
console.log(item); // now you have jquery object
```

Comment: Yes, making "typeof" shows object, Firefox is a liar then. But anyway thanks, it solved my problem .